# Ember.js load jquery on template render (no refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have created an ember.js template (about.hbs). I want to run some jQuery on the page but the jQuery only works if I reload the page.

I don't really get where I am meant to put the jQuery code to make it run when the template is rendered. At them moment I have put it in the controller.

```
   App.AboutController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
       $(document).ready(function() {
         //my jquery code
       });
    });
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to lifecycle callbacks ([see Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/)). When a template is rendered Ember will trigger the `didInsertElement` callback.  You can simply add your own code to this function, and if you want to use any jQuery inside of that callback you must keep the scope in mind: `this.$()`

Your code will look like this:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  this.$() //jquery code
}
```

Comment: So does that go in the controller? I have the following code and it still does not seem to work.

App.AvoutController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      didInsertElement: function(){
       this.$()
      // Launch Intro
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#launchIntro').on("touchstart click", function() {
          $('.intro-overlay').fadeOut();
          $('#intro-slider').fadeIn();
        });
      });
     }
    });

Comment: Or is this how it is meant to go in the controller? This doesn't seem to work either.
`didInsertElement: function ()  {
  this.$('.intro-overlay').fadeOut();
}`

Comment: `didInsertElement` is a callback of views and components.

Comment: Code that interacts with the DOM should go in the view, components are a type of view.